# Javascript Map Function compile error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following array of objects (as shown below) as **graphdatalogs**

[image]

I am trying to create a new array of objects called **graphdata** with **x** and **y** as properties from **graphdatalogs**

I tried the following javascript map method but I am getting compile error as shown below.

```
return this.state.graphdataLogs.rows._array.map( 
    (ae) => (graphdata.push(x:ae.logstringdate.substring(4,10),y:metricweight));
    );
```

[image]

Error Message

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected , (Fatal)
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the curly braces

```
return this.state.graphdataLogs.rows._array.map( 
    (ae) => (graphdata.push({x:ae.logstringdate.substring(4,10), y:metricweight}));
);
```